# printwriter not creating text file

Tags: java, user-interface, printwriter

I'm having trouble figuring out why the printwriter wont create a file when you type it in the output file textfield i cant move on until i figure out whats the problem. this program is a gui which calculates interest and outputs it into a text file but i cant seem to get that part to work i'd really appreciate it if someone could take a look at it theres only one printwriter in the whole program so far i intend on adding more once i get past this obstacle. im not sure whats wrong with the print writer.

```java
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InterestCal {

  public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Interest Computer");

        f.setSize(500, 300);

        JTabbedPane tabObj = new JTabbedPane();


        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,3,3));

        tabObj.addTab("Simple",null,panel1,"FirstPanel");

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        tabObj.addTab("Compound",null,panel2,"Second Panel");

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        tabObj.addTab("Continuous",panel3);

        //add the tabs to the panel
        f.add(tabObj);
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,3,3));

        //PANEL NUMBER 1
        JLabel principal1 = new JLabel("Principal $");
        JLabel annual1 = new JLabel("Annual % Rate");
        JLabel Years1 = new JLabel("Years");
        JLabel outputFile1 = new JLabel("Output File");
        JTextField principalField1  = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField annualField1     = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField YearsField1      = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField outputFileField1 = new JTextField ("");

        //PANEL NUMBER 1
        //adds label then adds text-field 
        panel1.add(principal1);
        panel1.add(principalField1); 

        panel1.add(annual1);
        panel1.add(annualField1);    

        panel1.add(Years1);
        panel1.add(YearsField1);     

        panel1.add(outputFile1);
        panel1.add(outputFileField1);


        JButton button1 = new JButton("Compute Simple Interest");
        panel1.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

                {


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int principalInPanel1 =       Integer.parseInt(principalField1.getText());
    double interestRateinPanel1 = Double.parseDouble(annualField1.getText());
    int yearsInPanel1 =           Integer.parseInt(YearsField1.getText());



    File filename =new File(outputFileField1.getText());
    //added this so i can use it outside the try/catch block
    PrintWriter writer = null; 
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    for (int x = 0; x < yearsInPanel1+1; x++) {

    double SimpleInterest = principalInPanel1*(Math.pow(1+interestRateinPanel1,x));


    writer.format("%d %.2f\n",x,SimpleInterest);
    System.out.printf(String.format("%d %.2f\n",x,SimpleInterest));
    }
            writer.close();
            System.exit(0);
            }


        });

        //PANEL NUMBER 2
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,3,3));
        JLabel principal2 = new JLabel("Principal $");
        JLabel annual2 = new JLabel("Annual % Rate");
        JLabel Years2 = new JLabel("Years");
        JLabel outputFile2 = new JLabel("Output File");
        JTextField principalField2  = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField annualField2     = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField YearsField2      = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField outputFileField2 = new JTextField ("");

        //PANEL NUMBER 2
        //adds label then adds text-field 
        panel2.add(principal2);
        panel2.add(principalField2); 

        panel2.add(annual2);
        panel2.add(annualField2);    

        panel2.add(Years2);
        panel2.add(YearsField2);     

        panel2.add(outputFile2);
        panel2.add(outputFileField2);

        //PANEL NUMBER 3
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,3,3));
        JLabel principal3 = new JLabel("Principal $");
        JLabel annual3 = new JLabel("Annual % Rate");
        JLabel Years3 = new JLabel("Years");
        JLabel outputFile3 = new JLabel("Output File");
        JTextField principalField3  = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField annualField3     = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField YearsField3      = new JTextField ("");
        JTextField outputFileField3 = new JTextField ("");

        //PANEL NUMBER 3
        //adds label then adds text-field 
        panel3.add(principal3);
        panel3.add(principalField3); 

        panel3.add(annual3);
        panel3.add(annualField3);    

        panel3.add(Years3);
        panel3.add(YearsField3);     

        panel3.add(outputFile3);
        panel3.add(outputFileField3);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working for me. Both with absolute and relative file path.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It’s a lot of code. I suggest you train [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Assuming you just enter a file name, e.g. `foo.txt`, the file will be created in the working directory. Are you sure you know which directory is the working directory for the Java program, i.e. are you sure you're looking in the right place for the file? Add `System.out.println(filename.getAbsolutePath());` to learn where the file is created.